# MySQL left join with lowest value of a group

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. Table one consists of all the metrics. Table two consists of all the articles.

I'm trying to get all the rows from the metric table extended with brand, priority and national_code of the corresponding article with the lowest priority.

```
SELECT national_code, brand, width, height, inch, `load`, speed, season, rof, MIN(`prio`) as prio FROM `whitelistarticles`
                            WHERE prio < 1000
                            GROUP BY
                            width, height, inch, `load`, speed,season,rof;

                            SELECT metrics.*, articles.national_code, articles.prio, articles.brand FROM whitelistmetrics as metrics
                            LEFT JOIN (SELECT national_code, brand, width, height, inch, `load`, speed, season, rof, MIN(`prio`) as prio FROM `whitelistarticles`
                            WHERE prio < 1000
                            GROUP BY
                            width, height, inch, `load`, speed,season,rof) as articles on
                            metrics.width = articles.width AND
                            metrics.height = articles.height AND
                            metrics.inch = articles.inch AND
                            metrics.load = articles.load AND
                            metrics.speed = articles.speed AND
                            metrics.season = articles.season AND
                            metrics.rof = articles.rof
                            WHERE articles.prio IS NOT NULL
                            ORDER BY width, height, inch, `load`, speed;
```

The issue is that this query gives me the lowest priority of a group, but not the row with the priority. It ends up giving me wrong brands and wrong national_codes while it picked the lowest priority of the group.

.e.g. two articles with the corresponding metrics, one has a priority of 20 and the other 15. I want the brand and national_code of the article with the priority of 15. It ends up giving me a priority of 15, with the national_code and brand name of the article with a priority of 20.

How do I fix this query so that it will join the row with the lowest priority instead of only the priority?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### This will help you

```
SELECT metrics.*, articles.national_code, articles.prio, articles.brand 
  FROM whitelistmetrics as metrics LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT a1.national_code, a1.brand, a1.width, a1.height, a1.inch, a1.`load`, a1.speed, a1.season, a1.rof, a2.prio
           FROM `whitelistarticles` a1 inner join 
                (SELECT national_code, brand, width, height, inch, `load`, speed, season, rof, MIN(`prio`) as prio 
                   FROM `whitelistarticles`
                  WHERE prio < 1000
                  GROUP BY width, height, inch, `load`, speed, season, rof
                ) a2 on a1.width = a2.width AND
                        a1.height = a2.height AND
                        a1.inch = a2.inch AND
                        a1.load = a2.load AND
                        a1.speed = a2.speed AND
                        a1.season = a2.season AND
                        a1.rof = a2.rof
                        a1.prio = a2.prio
        ) as articles on metrics.width = articles.width AND
                         metrics.height = articles.height AND
                         metrics.inch = articles.inch AND
                         metrics.load = articles.load AND
                         metrics.speed = articles.speed AND
                         metrics.season = articles.season AND
                         metrics.rof = articles.rof
 WHERE articles.prio IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY width, height, inch, `load`, speed, season, rof;
```